# What is shared between train and inference decoder in seq2seq model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network, seq2seq

I am currently working on a seq2seq model but unable to understand what is shared between a train decoder and a inference decoder.

Answer (score 0):

In a seq2seq architecture, in it's simplest form you have one RNN cell (e.g. LSTM or GRU or vanilla RNN) for encoder and another RNN cell for decoder. During training you update the weight matrices in the these units. Once training is done you fix and save the learned weight matrices. And during inference you use the same encoder and decoder units (as in RNN units with the saved weight matrices).

What differs during training and inference is mainly the you would the decoder RNN cell. While training one usually feeds the ground truth tokens to the decoder at every time step. Whereas, during inference, you use the decoder to compute tokens ids for output sequence one by one and feed it back.